# How to handle PushNotification alert buttons when app is in minimized sate in iphone?

Tags: iphone, push-notification

When my app is in minimized state and when that time push notification alert comes with two buttons close and view. I want to open particular screen in app when user click view button on alert.

When app is open state that time I can handle push notification by using below method
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo

If any one knows how to handle push notification alert buttons when app is in minimized state please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah

When The App is brought into running state via Notifications..This method is fired

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

You can then retrieve the notification received from the `launchOptions` dictionary and open the appropriate screen.

Comment: Please can you tell me how retrieve data from launchOptions dictionary when I click on view button of push notification alert.

Comment: Paste this code in the method mentioned above: if (launchOptions != nil)
 {
  NSDictionary* dictionary = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
  if (dictionary != nil)
  {
   NSLog(@"Launched from push notification: %@", dictionary);
  }
 }

Comment: Please tick the answer, if you find it to be correct. Should there be any further related issue, I'd reply to that.

Comment: I am getting below dictionary  
{"aps":{"sound":"default","alert":{"body":"From Franklin Av To Grand Army Plaza03:56:30 - 03:58:30","action-loc-key":"View"},"badge":1},"user_id":"1","start_station_id":"239N","node_id":"75"} 
can you tell me how to get body and 3 id from this dictionary please help me.

Comment: the notification you're receiving is from the server. I mean..you should format it from simpler retrieval..however, this style of notification is also permissible by Apple. So what you can do here is 
NSString* alertValue = [[[userInfo valueForKey:@"aps"] valueForKey:@"alert"] valueForKey:@"body"];

Comment: One more doubt when app is minimized then how to get info of Notification. Which method is getting called when we click view button when app is minimized. Above method is getting called only when app is closed not minimized. Please help me if know.

Comment: the same method will be called. Trying NSLogging the notification..and comment here what appears